# Limit MongoDB database size?

Tags: mongodb

We're interested in deploying MongoDB, but we need to know if we can limit database/table sizes?

For example:

db.user1.find()
db.user2.find()

As you can see from the above, each user will have their own database.  We want to limit each user's database so we don't have any one user eating up all our hard drive space.

Is this possible with MongoDB?

Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was called a "database" or "table;" that's why I gave the db.user1 and db.user2 examples.

Comment: There are no databases or tables, there are collections which are created the moment they're referenced, or in advance as per @Falcon's answer. If in advance, you can specify a maximum size, and whether it's a capped collection or not. In a capped collection, when the maximum data size is reached, old rows are deleted as new rows are inserted, by insertion time.

Comment: So a capped collection won't necessarily work well for user registration/login, right? (Since old user rows will be deleted)

Comment: @Dan, huh? No databases? Are you sure about that? I don't wanna be sarcastic but the MongoDB's official site states "MongoDB (from "humongous") is a scalable, high-performance, open source, document-oriented DATABASE (emphasis)"

Comment: @chris Yeah, sure, but db.user1.find() and db.user2.find() refer to two different *collections*, not two databases. "Database" means different things in different contexts. To Oracle, it's a physical thing on disk. To MySQL, it's just a namespace. In your quote, it's referring to the dictionary definition, that MongoDB itself is a system for organizing a body of data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a database per user and enable the --quota option. This will allow you keep any user from using too much space.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#core-options

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#faq-disk-size

Answer (score 1):

Try to

```
db.createCollection("mycoll", {size:100000})
```

Comment: Capped collections are not a good idea in general since they have some limitations; You can't delete from them or update docs to a larger doc -- docs can't grow.

Comment: createCollection create capped collection? And it i say cappet : false ?